# stop reading of two or more characters in switch case statement in C

Tags: c

My C Code
My code is working well, my problem when I pressed AB, it takes both the cases at single time. How to avoid this, when I entered AB, it should display error message instead of taking as input.
I tried lot of possible ways, but couldn't find it.

```
    while(bal>=0){
        printf("Enter char:");
        scanf(" %c",&val);
        switch(val){
            case 'a':
            case 'A':
               statement1;
               break;
            case 'b':
            case 'B':
               statement2;
               break;
            default:
               statement 3 (error);
               break;
           }
         }
```

Also I leave a space in scanf function.

Comment: hi, i tired like `scanf(" %s",&val);` to get input for case, this time it takes 1st char as input and works for that input, but not showing the error message.

Comment: By reading a string and checking it has a single character.

Comment: Of course you can't read a string into a single character. Use an array such as `char input[16]; scanf("%15s", input); if(strlen(input) == 1) switch (input[0]) ...`

Comment: @WeatherVane thankyou for your reply, how can i display the error message (default case), if i entered more than one character for my input.

Comment: How about `scanf(" %c%c",&val,&next);`? Check that `scanf` returned 2 and that `next` is a whitespace character (or that `next` is a newline character if that is more desirable behavior for you).

Comment: Here's a variation of the above: `char val = input[0]; if(strlen(input) != 1) val = 'X';` and then do the switch cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might perform a follow-on test for additional characters, and if so, alert the user at that point.  Following is a bit of refactored code that I believe addresses your issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char val, ch;

    while (1)
    {
        printf("Enter char:");
        scanf(" %c",&val);
        while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF)
            if (ch != '\n')
            {
                val = 'X';
            }
        switch(val)
        {
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
            printf("Case A selected\n");
            break;
        case 'b':
        case 'B':
            printf("Case B selected\n");
            break;
        case '0':
            return 0;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Whoops\n");
            break;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Utilizing the "getchar" function would allow for testing of subsequent character entries and allow for the redirection of the switch block to an error message.  Following was a simple test of this refactored code.

```
@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/CharType/bin/Release$ ./CharType 
Enter char:A
Case A selected
Enter char:B
Case B selected
Enter char:AB
Whoops
Enter char:V
Whoops
Enter char:B
Case B selected
Enter char:BB
Whoops
Enter char:0
@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/CharType/bin/Release$
```

You might give that try to see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Comment: `ch` should be an `int` so that it can be compared to `EOF`.

Comment: Good point.  I need to go get another cup of coffee.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with line-based user input, it is usually better to read a whole line at a time using the function [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), instead of only reading one character at a time using the function `scanf`. That way, you can use the function [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) on the string entered by the user, to determine how many characters the user entered on the line.

Also, instead of comparing with `'a'`, `'A'`, `'b'` and `'B'`, it is simpler to first convert the character to upper-case using the function [`toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper). That way, you only have to compare with `'A'` and `'B'`, but not with `'a'` and `'b'`.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

//forward declaration
void get_line_from_user( const char prompt[], char buffer[], int buffer_size );

int main( void )
{
    for (;;) //infinite loop, equivalent to while(1)
    {
        char line[200];

        get_line_from_user( "Enter char: ", line, sizeof line );

        if ( strlen(line) != 1 )
        {
            printf( "Error: Please enter exactly one character!\n" );
            continue;
        }

        switch ( toupper( (unsigned char)line[0] ) )
        {
            case 'A':
                printf( "Input valid. You entered A.\n" );
                break;
            case 'B':
                printf( "Input valid. You entered B.\n" );
                break;
            default:
                printf( "Error: Invalid input!\n" );
        }
    }
}

//This function will read exactly one line of input from the
//user. It will remove the newline character, if it exists. If
//the line is too long to fit in the buffer, then the function
//will automatically reprompt the user for input. On failure,
//the function will never return, but will print an error
//message and call "exit" instead.
void get_line_from_user( const char prompt[], char buffer[], int buffer_size )
{
    for (;;) //infinite loop, equivalent to while(1)
    {
        char *p;

        //prompt user for input
        fputs( prompt, stdout );

        //attempt to read one line of input
        if ( fgets( buffer, buffer_size, stdin ) == NULL )
        {
            printf( "Error reading from input!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //attempt to find newline character
        p = strchr( buffer, '\n' );

        //make sure that entire line was read in (i.e. that
        //the buffer was not too small to store the entire line)
        if ( p == NULL )
        {
            int c;

            //a missing newline character is ok if the next
            //character is a newline character or if we have
            //reached end-of-file (for example if the input is
            //being piped from a file or if the user enters
            //end-of-file in the terminal itself)
            if ( (c=getchar()) != '\n' && !feof(stdin) )
            {
                if ( ferror(stdin) )
                {
                    printf( "Error reading from input!\n" );
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }

                printf( "Input was too long to fit in buffer!\n" );

                //discard remainder of line
                do
                {
                    c = getchar();

                    if ( ferror(stdin) )
                    {
                        printf( "Error reading from input!\n" );
                        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                    }

                } while ( c != '\n' && c != EOF );

                //reprompt user for input by restarting loop
                continue;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //remove newline character by overwriting it with
            //null character
            *p = '\0';
        }

        //input was ok, so break out of loop
        break;
    }
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
Enter char: 
Error: Please enter exactly one character!
Enter char: AB
Error: Please enter exactly one character!
Enter char: a
Input valid. You entered A.
Enter char: A
Input valid. You entered A.
Enter char: b
Input valid. You entered B.
Enter char: c
Error: Invalid input!
```

Comment: Nicely explained -- and -- commented `:)`